# mod_rewrite: How to I permit a user with no redirection/rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm working with mod_rewrite for Windows (via an ISAPI filter) and haven't yet seen documentation on how to set up RewriteRule to permit the existing url with no changes.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*iPhone.* [NC]
RewriteRule () http://DontWantToRedirect/orAlterURL [R,NC,L]
```

My goal is to create a rule to permit only iPhones with OS 4.0.1 to connect to my server.  There are other rules in play here, so I have to keep the logic if - then - passthrough w/no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not rewrite a URL with RewriteRule try just using a dash as the rewritten path...

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```